# Qt Use Same Settings Between Two Apps

Tags: qt, settings, system

I have two projects that both use the settings:

```
QSettings settings(
                QSettings::SystemScope,
                QCoreApplication::organizationName(),
                QCoreApplication::applicationName());
```

I was under the impression that with SystemScome and the same application and organization names that these settings would be linked. But they aren't. What's the best approach for this?

Thanks!

EDIT:

It was on Linux, and I believe sudo needed to be used for SystemScope. UserScope did however work.

Answer (score 0):

As it is thoroughly written in documentation - [QSettings: Platform Specific Notes](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qsettings.html#platform-specific-notes) the path which QSettings use to store settings is uniquely determined by application and organization name parameters.

The First thing you could do is to check is settings are truly being written in location mentioned in link above for your system and what is different for those two applications. For example, there is a singular case that for windows their will be different for x86 and x64 applications.

Also if you try to use them simultaneously for both applications you should remember to use `sync ()` function or create new `QSettings` instances when it's needed so the apps wouldn't conflict in operating on them.